# ¿Puedo ejecutar un script despues de que cargue por completo la pantalla?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop1.7

Contextualizo

Estoy trabajando con prestashop y sus módulos.
Estos me permiten hacer cambios en ciertos formularios con javascript y jQuery,
pero si otro modulo se instala y realiza cambios ahí, estos se ejecutaran de los últimos y mis cambios se verán pisados.

¿Como podría hacer que mi script se ejecute después de que sus cambios de realicen?

Estoy atento a sus comentarios. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Intenta correr el script en el método onload del objeto window.

```
window.onload = function() {
  //código a ejecutar
};
```

Comment: Estoy usando esta funcion para ejecutarlo  
`if (document.addEventListener){ window.addEventListener('load',camposaddress,false);}
else{ window.attachEvent('onload',camposaddress);}`

aun asi, las otras funciones se siguen ejecutando despues de las mias

Comment: Prueba con window.onload = function() {
  if (document.addEventListener){ window.addEventListener('load',camposaddress,false);} else{ window.attachEvent('onload',camposaddress);}
};

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código es lo que Google recomienda. Este código debe colocarse en el código HTML justo antes de la etiqueta < /body > (al final del archivo HTML).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "miscript.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

Con este código se consigue que todo el documento cargue primero y luego cargue el archivo “miscript.js” externo. Hay que tener en cuenta la ruta del archivo dependiendo de dónde se coloque en el servidor. Para el código anterior, el JS externo, se encuentra en la raíz del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, intenta con `.ready()`, pues este método de Jquery permite hacer cosas inmediatamente después de haber cargado el contenido de la página y todos los elementos del DOM hayan cargado. Te dejo un ejemplito:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Código a ejecutar una vez haya cargado la página, html, librerías etc..
  
  alert('Me ejecuto después de haber cargado toda la página');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Página con contenido</h1>
```